# to Find out accuracy of a model in Python using decision tree

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am very new in Python, So I was trying to run the below code and I want to find accuracy but this program is not displaying accuracy nor any error.
I have tried again and again but its still not displaying. I use jupyter notebook. I am using two datasets(csv) in this program.

def DecisionTree():

```
from sklearn import tree

clf3 = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()   # empty model of the decision tree
clf3 = clf3.fit(X,y)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred=clf3.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred,normalize=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
print(clf3.score(X_test, y_test))
```